# Why is my random value getting overwritten almost instantly?

Tags: javascript, css

I am having a problem with my code. I try to make objects spawn in random locations as you can see with `drawHyperBall()`, and, `getRandomIntX()`, and `getRandomIntY()`. What is happening though, is the random value gets overwritten almost instantly. How can I fix this?

Code below:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var x = canvas.width/2;
var y = canvas.height/2;
var ballRadius = 40;
var hBallRadius = 10;
var w = 5;
var hunger = 630;
var hypo = 0;
var hyper = 0;
var randomX;
var randomY;
var Keys = {
     up: false,
        down: false,
        left: false,
        right: false
};
 
function drawBall() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#00FF00";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.lineWidth= 3.5;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}
 
function drawConceBar() {
 ctx.strokeRect(100,930,630,30)
}
 
function drawHungerBar() {
 ctx.fillStyle = "#73591C";
 ctx.fillRect(1140,930,hunger,30)
 ctx.fillStyle = "black";
 ctx.strokeRect(1140,930,630,30)
}

function drawTitle() {
 ctx.fillStyle = "black";
 ctx.font = "120px Arial";
 ctx.fillText("Osmos.is",canvas.width/2 -210,120);
}
function drawBorder() {
 ctx.strokeRect(100,150,1670,730);
}
 
function getRandomIntX(minX,maxX) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxX- minX + 1)) + minX;
}
function getRandomIntY(minY,maxY) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxY - minY + 1)) + minY;
}

function drawHyperBall() {
 ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(getRandomIntX(110, 1660), getRandomIntY(160, 720), hBallRadius, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}
 
function draw() {
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 
 drawBall();
 
 drawBorder();
  
 drawTitle();
  
 drawConceBar();
  
 drawHungerBar();
  
 if(y > 830) {
     y -= 5;
 }
 else if(y < 195) {
     y += 5;
 }
 
 if(x < 150) {
  x += 5;
 }
 else if(x > 1720) {
  x -= 5;
 }
  
 if (Keys.up) {
     y -= 5;
 }
 else if (Keys.down) {
     y += 5;
 }

 if (Keys.left) {
     x -= 5;
 }
 else if (Keys.right) {
     x += 5;
 }
 
 if (hunger <= 0) {
  hunger += 1;
 }
 else {
  hunger -= 1;
 }
}
 
window.onkeydown = function(e) {
    var kc = e.keyCode;
    e.preventDefault();
    if      (kc === 37) Keys.left = true;  // only one key per event
    else if (kc === 38) Keys.up = true;    // so check exclusively
    else if (kc === 39) Keys.right = true;
    else if (kc === 40) Keys.down = true;
};
 
window.onkeyup = function(e) {
    var kc = e.keyCode;
    e.preventDefault();
    if      (kc === 37) Keys.left = false;
    else if (kc === 38) Keys.up = false;
    else if (kc === 39) Keys.right = false;
    else if (kc === 40) Keys.down = false;
};

setInterval(draw, 10);
setInterval(drawHyperBall, 1000);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: You're clearing the canvas every 10ms which is clearing the ball you've just drawn....

Comment: @david if I stop clearing the canvas, the trails of objects don't get deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the problem. I was clearing all of the canvas, so I added a new function that would clear only specific things.

Comment: A more common solution is to store all the 'hyperball' locations in an array and redraw them every frame.

Comment: @david Well, my own solution is working out pretty well, I would mark this question as answered but it is telling me, "You can accept your own answer in 5 hours", so I'm just waiting for that.